# Why is emacs freezing and how can I prevent it? (likely involving org agenda)

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, debugging

What would cause emacs to "mostly" freeze when creating an org agenda?

I say "mostly" because when you type `C-g`, it does show "Quit" in the minibuffer, and the time logging number in the minibuffer still increments. Nothing else seems to respond though that I could think of.

I was only able to get emacs to respond by getting the emacs pid with `ps aux | grep emacs` and then running `kill -SIGUSR2 {PID}`.

After that, emacs opened a buffer with:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  redisplay_internal\ \(C\ function\)()
```

What can I do to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Does this happen when you start emacs with `emacs -q`?

Comment: It happens rarely, and is only reproducible within a session. If it happens once, it will likely happen again, but I can't get it to happen reliably. I haven't seen it happen with `emacs -q`, but I haven't tried running a `-q` session for days opening 100's of files (and even when I do that with a normal session I usually have no issues).

Comment: Find an answer? Getting a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Check your `org-agenda-files` variable for file duplicates that are in separate directories.

Context: I had the same issue with Doom Emacs after I had copied org files to a new directory and added the newly copied files to the `org-agenda-files` variable without removing the original files from `org-agenda-files`.

Remove the unneeded files from `org-agenda-files` by opening the offending file in a buffer and typing `C-c ]` or `M-x org-remove-file RET`.